# Rviz Visualization Topic in Gazebo

Tags: rviz, gazebo-8

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am looking to visualize some objects in gazebo, however, I don't  actually want them to be apart of the physical environment. I know that rviz has a topic called "visualization_marker" In which you can publish different types of markers via the visualization_msgs.msg structure.

Is there a away to do this Gazebo too?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24703/rviz-visualization-topic-in-gazebo/) by [H](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21038/h/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, Gazebo also has visualization markers, see this example: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo11/examples/stand_alone/marker/

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [H](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21038/h/) on 2020-04-01**:
Thank you this worked. Do you know if it is possible to replicate this in python?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-04-01**:
We don't have a python interface to ign-transport yet, so no easy way yet. I guess you could use ROS and the ros_ign bridge, but marker messages aren't supported yet.

**Comment by [TheClem](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43300/theclem/) on 2021-02-22**:
hello, the link is broken. Can you update the link or explain how to do it?